# Where exactly is EUID, EGID etc. of a process stored?

Tags: linux, permissions, process

I was just reading some articles about permissions in Linux and I found out that this was never mentioned there. I wonder how it works.

**Example situation:** Binary file `read_file.out` that reads file `~/file.txt` and prints its content to `stdout` is executed. This creates a process and the system decides whether it can or can not read `~/file.txt` based on `EUID` and/or `EGID` of the user who created of the process.

Where exactly are these values stored? Where does the system look in order to say
"*I see your EUID is 1002, so you can read this file.*"
or
"*Your EUID is 1003 which means you can not read it and you are also member of no group that can access this file so I will not allow you to read it.*"?

I found out that there are some files in the pseudo-filesystem `/proc/<pid>/`, especially `/proc/<pid>/stat` and `/proc/<pid>/status` (better readable version of `stat`). Are these the files according to which the system decides the permissions or are they just "informational" files that serve only as a source to commands like `ps`?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the kernel data structures. The virtual files in `/proc/<pid>/` are just views into them. Now, I could dig up the source code, but I doubt it's really useful. There's probably just a simple C struct for each process, that contains fields for all of the UIDs and GIDs plus a table of secondary groups along other per-process data.

Comment: To be more specific, it's an `unsigned int` stored in a variable of type [`kuid_t`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.12/source/include/linux/uidgid.h#L20), which itself is stored in `current->cred->euid`, where `cred` is a struct of type [`cred`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.12/source/include/linux/cred.h#L110) and `current` is the well-known per-process [`task_struct`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.12/source/include/linux/sched.h#L483) struct.